# Puppet agent doesn't run manifest from regexp

Tags: puppet

```
node 'node-slave01' {
        include repo::git
        include fun::cmatrix
}
node 'node-slave02' {
        include repo::hg
        include fun::toilet
}
node 'node-slave03' {
        include fun::rup
        include repo::svn
        include fun::cmatrix
}
node 'node-slave04' {
        include repo::git
        include repo::hg
        include repo::svn
        include fun::cmatrix
        include fun::toilet
}
node /node-slave\d+/ {
        include lamp
        include test
        include fun::rup
        include sup
}
```

So everything in `/node-slave\d+/` doesn't run. If I take the `sup` module and put it under any of the 4 nodes, it runs after I write `sudo puppet agent --test`, but not if it's under the regexp.

How do I do it if I want to have certain nodes do certain things, but there are some commands that I want all of them to do? Writing `include sup` under every node seems extremely annoying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puppet matches one node and once it does that it stops.    FQDN is highest and it works down to default.   See matching section  - https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/4.10/lang_node_definitions.html.

One way to do it is to have just your regex node and then use a case statement for things that are unique to each node

node /node-slave\d+/ {
        include lamp
        include test
        include fun::rup
        include sup

case $::hostname {
      'node-slave01': {
             include repo::git
              include fun::cmatrix
                      }
      node-slave02': {
      include repo::hg
      include fun::toilet
                     }
   
         }
}